# Canvas open website in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have buttons on my canvas and want one of them to open a website in a new tab, is this possible?

I know how to make something happen if the user clicks within my button I am just lost on how to do the actual opening of website part?

Comment: window.open(), but as is stated in the link @ChrisSobolewski posted, you can't determine whether the browser opens a window, a tab, or completely ignores your request.